# Create own slider using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here, I want to create image slider using animate event.
But when I clicked one time image not replace when I click second time image replace.

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      var img = "<img src='images/img" + i + ".jpg' />";
      var $lefty = $j('.image').html(img);
      $lefty.animate({
        left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0
      }, function() {
        var $marginLefty = $j('.image').html(img);
        $marginLefty.animate({
          marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ?
            $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
        });
      });
      if (i == 4)
        i = 0;
      i++;
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
 .slide .inner {
   left: 60px;
   bottom: 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
    <button>slide it</button>
    <div class="inner">
      <img id="img" src="images/audi_r8_in_snow-1280x720.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

It work when click event perform two times.
but I want single time performance that image will change.
Thank you.

Comment: How about  $('.inner').html(img);    This should be 'html' not 'text'. Not sure if this will solve the problem but it is not advisable to use text if you are trying update HTML

Comment: only for testing purpose you can replace it with `$('.inner').html(img)`.
I updated code. Its display image but problem not solved.

Comment: Do you understand what `.animate({width:'toggle'})` does? Think about it. You click the button, `width: 'toggle'` changes the width to `0`. You click the button again, and it animates to whatever width it's supposed to be. You click it again, it animates to `width: 0`. Did you read about `width: 'toggle'` before you tried to use it?

Comment: Sorry but I read this `animate({width:'toggle'})`

Comment: You are linking to jQuery twice in the document head. Other than that a fiddle would be very convenient here to show the exact issue.

Comment: used code snippet to view result easily.

Comment: I'm very confused... what is the scope of `$j` inside of `$(document).ready()`? Is it different from `$`?

Comment: I updated my code as per your confusion

Comment: We cannot reproduce your snippet since all your image paths point to a local directory!